# Filter Calendars or Event Resource using lastmodifiedDateTime on Microsoft Graph APIs

Tags: events, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

My aim is to check the last time an event was modified in my calendar using Microsoft Graph.
I am trying to filter on **lastModifiedDateTime** but it seems to not be working.

Sample query :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startdatetime=2020-08-01&enddatetime=2020-09-01&$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge 2020-08-30T14:46:00.3343565Z
```

Regards,
Aarushi

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a Filter with a CalendarView so you need to choose either one or the other. For what your trying to do change tracking would probably be a better approach though https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-events

Comment: Hi Glen , I want to capture the last change made to the events for a particular user. So I am aiming at lastModifiedDateTime with CalendarView or Events resource.